# Huge 50GB+ kernel dump files being generated in temp

Tags: windows-10, storage, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

These folders/files keep appearing and I keep having to delete them. They are constantly sucking away all my storage space - what's going on?

[image]

Tried opening in Event Viewer & nothing shows up:

[image]

Tried converting the log and still nothing shows but log gets even more massive:

[image]

Comment: Those files are Windows event logs, what events, are contained within them?

Comment: Look in the logs to see what's happening.

Comment: How do you suggest reading them? Are you suggesting to open the 20GB file with notepad?

Comment: Egigma - Open **Event Viewer** | **Action** | **Open Saved Log** and go from there to point to one of the ETL files. I believe EV will only display what you are looking at and not all data at once as notepad.exe does or whatever.

Comment: Tried doing that & nothing is showing up. I have two options; view log as is or convert it. Converting it does a x7 expansion on the already massive size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was/is the Visual Studio 2019 CPU & Memory diagnostic component. After turning this off, the massive log files stopped being generated.